# Disputed flags are very disputed

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I am trying to understand the flagging on stackoverflow. So here is the case. The questions which are disputed are as follows.

[image: List of Disputed Flags]

The first Question was [How to make groups in different columns in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626930/how-to-make-groups-in-different-columns-in-crystal-reports) does only have a link to a image which shows how the data is and how OP wanted to arrange. This is question seriously has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed. That is what i did but it is disputed. Attaching the image also so that even if the question is removed we know how it looks like.

[image: This is how a disputed question looks like]

Now comes to another question which is [Download gmail emails and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625944/download-gmail-emails-and-print) which says `I have a query, Is this possible to download the gmail emails using dot net code? If possible please share the relevant links. thanks.` I believe it is not a good question for SO community. Since OP is asking for links, Secondly answer to the question could only be yes or no. in this case yes. Thirdly no efforts shown no code nothing. So I marked it Low Quality. Yet it is also disputed.

[image: Another Disputed flagged Question]

So now My question is how and when should we flag the question? What is wrong with these questions?

Comment: How did you even flag those as VLQ? Just use an ordinary close vote (unclear, too broad, etc).

Comment: @AndrewMedico: isnt that questions VLQ?? Closing vote has also been added on top of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd say you flagged the first one appropriately; there's nowhere near enough information to begin to make sense of what he wants there - it is indeed quite unlikely that anyone can or will salvage anything from it.

The second one though, it's pretty obvious what he wants to do - indeed, you understood it well enough to find a duplicate. So marking it as a duplicate would suffice.

But in any case, "disputed" doesn't mean "wrong" - it just means others disagreed with you. [These folks](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14303931) and [these other folks](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14303315) didn't think those respective questions were unsalvageable. I disagree pretty strongly with the first group, so I've asked them to take a couple of days away from review.

Comment: Thanks for such a beautiful description. If you could also let me know more on `when should we flag the question?` will also enlighten me to carry fwd with SO neatly.

Comment: Flag the question whenever there's a problem you don't know how to handle any other way, @Mohit. If you can fix it yourself, do that. So if you can edit, edit. If you can answer, answer. If you can close, close. If you can delete, delete. If you can't or don't know what to do, flag.

Comment: I think those "Requires Editing" reviewers are [just confused what "Requires Editing" actually means](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285944/262399) (H&I reviewers have to deal with it) versus what the interface guidance says ("by the author or others").  It's unlikely that a question as bad as that can be edited into shape by anyone, but I think better guidance could have led the reviewers to the correct decision.  (I'm not arguing you shouldn't ban/re-educate them now, but in the long run it's more efficient to help people do the right thing in the first place.)

Comment: You've gotta be pretty optimistic to think that the author of that post is going to be able to fix it, @Jeffrey. We could rename it "not excruciatingly bad" I guess.

Comment: "Looks OK", "I can edit it" and "Should be closed" are better, maybe?  We couldn't actually say "I can edit it" because they'd expect to edit right away, but it would make them think about _who_ could edit it, and in this case I doubt any of them can.  Softening Unsalvageable into "should be closed" might make people more likely give up on the question rather than hoping for a heroic edit, but might be a problem if a spam question got in.

Comment: Don't take those as specific suggestions -- I don't know the magic words here either.  But if you're still serious about Triage I think it's worth brainstorming and A/B testing, is what I mean to say.  Or maybe you think the error rate is already as low as it will get?  Just think about it, is my point.  I feel like Triage was instituted and and then just neglected.  (And I'll move on now.)

Comment: First of all, “Requires editing” really sounds like that the post will be temporarily suspended for the *author* to fix it; in contrast, “Should be slosed” or “Unsalvageable” sounds like the post is hopeless and should be deleted or hidden forever. Second, flagging a post requires spending a credit, while “Requires editing” does not, so people think the latter is not a big deal indeed. And the last, but not least, is that low-rep reviewers simply cannot see what happens in the H&I queue, so they do not and cannot realize what are the consequences of them pressing “Requires editing”.

Comment: By the way, the “Help and Improvement” queue on StackOverflow currently has 280 items in queue, while the “Close votes” queue counts above 8000. So, a question sent to “Requires editing” may in fact be processed faster than “Unsalvageable”. (Correct me if I am wrong here, please, as I am not familiar with either queue.)

Comment: I just lost count of how many times I saw this discussion on what "Requires Editing" really means. IMO, the people behind SO don't give value to the weight behind the word "Unsalvageable". To start with, "off-topic/MCVE" does not look unsalvageable. If the author can edit their question to include an MCVE, it is certainly **salvageable throught editing**. This dyssonance seems easily fixable, to me, if MCVE is simply moved to be a sub-option of "Requires Editing" instead of "Unsalvageable".